# Web.config replacement, missing section

Tags: asp.net

I've spent a day on this 'simple' problem...

I'm using Web Deployment Projects to deploy my MVC3 webapp. I tell it to replace the appSettings section with one in a config file by entering

```
appSettings=Config\AppSettings.Production.config;
```

That works perfectly. The resulting (deployed) Web.config file has been correctly transformed and now contains the production settings I told it to use.

But, trying to do the same thing with a custom section 'spring' using exactly the same method

```
spring=Config\Spring.Production.config;
```

...I get...

*web.config(1): error WDP00002: missing section spring*

The spring section is at exactly the same level as the appSettings element, so I don't know why it doesn't work.

There are loads of other people with the same problem, but no satisfactory answers that I can find.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax to reference external file is like this:

```
<spring configSource="Config\Spring.Production.config" />
```

The `file="Config\AppSettings.Production.config"` syntax  that works with `appSettings` section won't work with custom sections as far as I remember, as they don't implement such property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I did wonder about using the configSource property, but doesn't that kind of hard-code the production version into my file (I'm quite new to this)? How could I point it at a different file for my testing environment (configSource=Config\Spring.Test.config)? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.. anyway without specifying the `configSource` attribute, it will look in the existing, root, `web.config` file as usual. And yes, you can point it to different files on test and production.

Comment: I think what I'm getting at it having a different file on a per-configuration basis i.e. Web.Production.config points at one file, and Web.Test.config points at another (or I guess the values could be in those files directly without having a configSource attribute. Just trying it now... thanks again

Comment: Hmmm, I created a Web.Production.config file with a different <spring> element in it, and when I publish my file in VS2010, the published version of the file has been correctly merged i.e. I have a single web.config, but it now contains the production settings I want for <spring>. However, I can't get Web Deployment Projects to respect the Web.Production.config file, which is a bit of a shame. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: PS I think you're right, the replacement feature doesnt work on custom config sections due to some sort of limitation with the builder, it needs to find the DLL of the handler which is a bit rubbish since I just want it to replace the text

Comment: Sorry, other than what I posted I don't have further idea.. you get any error?

Comment: No worries, thanks very much for your help anyway - really appreciate it

Comment: PS nope, no errors, I think its a case of limitations of the tools really. I think what I really need to do is learn how MSBuild (or NAnt) work properly and write a proper build script. Was being lazy and trying to avoid it (since what I have already is soooo close to what I need) but it'll be a good thing for me to learn in any case.

Comment: Cheers mate, sorry I can't be of more help! :/